# Combining similar query results into one row

Tags: mysql

I have

```
ID username group
1  philip   football
2  george   baseball
3  alice    football
4  ani      football
5  george   football
```

and trying to make this

```
username   group
philip     football
george     baseball, football
alice      football
ani        football
```

In other words I want to combine the grop idetms into one string like here "baysboll, football"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `GROUP_CONCAT` function

```
 select username, GROUP_CONCAT(group) FROM table GROUP BY Username
```

Answer (score 3):

don't forget to escape the column `Group` with backtick in order to avoid syntax error. `GROUP` is a **[Reserved Keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)**.

```
SELECT username, GROUP_CONCAT(`group`) 
FROM table
GROUP BY userName
```